# Four Real roots of sextic polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Given a general sextic polynomial with real coefficients

$$f(x)=x^6+a_5 x^5+a_4 x^4+a_3 x^3+a_2 x^2+a_1 x+a_0$$

is there a way to determine whether there are 1) six real roots; 2) four real roots; 3) no real roots just based on the $\{a_i\}$ coefficients of the polynomial? I am particularly interested in case 2). That is to say, what condition should we have on $\{a_i\}$ to ensure that four real roots exist?

Comment: Not entirely too sure on this, but it looks like [Sturm's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) may have some use here? Looks like [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) could help as well.

Comment: You might like to look into [root isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-root_isolation).

Answer (score 0):

For $|x|\gt A=1+|a_0|+|a_1|+..+|a_5|$, the polynomial is always positive.  Sturm sequence then can be used to determine number of real roots $\gt -(A+1)$.

Comment: Your first sentence is false. For a counterexample, take e.g. $f(x)=x^6-\frac12x$, so that $A=\frac12$. But $f(\frac34)=(\frac34)^6-(\frac34)^2<0$.

Comment: Sorry. I need to add 1.  Corrected.

Comment: OK, I can believe it now! But is there a simple proof of this fact?

Comment: @TonK  The idea is simple enough.  A has to be large enough that the $A^6$ term is greater than all other terms combined, so the polynomial for $x\lt -A$ is always positive.